# List AJP connections between httpd and Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, bash, apache, tomcat

On a CentOS 7 server, `httpd` is configured to use `AJP` to route `http` traffic to a `Tomcat` instance running on the same server.

**What specific `bash` commands will list and count the `AJP` connections that exist between `httpd` and `tomcat`?**

In case it helps, here is the background:

The `httpd` configuration that sends requests to Tomcat via `AJP` is:

```
[root@remote-host-name ~]# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/mydomain.com.conf

<VirtualHost www.mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_com_requests.log combined
    ProxyPass / ajp://my.public.ip.addr:8012/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://my.public.ip.addr:8012/
</VirtualHost>
```

And the Tomcat config for receiving the `AJP`-routed connections includes:

```
[root@remote-host-name ~]# vi /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
.....
      <Connector port="8012" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8446" connectionTimeout="10000" keepAliveTimeout="10000" />
.....
```

**How do I list and count the live AJP connections between `httpd` and `tomcat` at any given moment?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use netstat to find the connections to ajp port 8012 here as per your config
    netstat -an | grep 8012